# What is the purpose of MathUtils.euclideanModulo, and how is it different from a regular modulo?

Tags: javascript, three.js, modulo

I'm a bit confused about the euclideanModulo method of mathutils in threejs.
I already know what a modulo symbol does, but the euclideanModulo looks quite different.

```
( ( n % m ) + m ) % m
```

I tried looking up the semantics of Euclidean, but it only says this:

> relating to or denoting the system of geometry based on the work of
> Euclid and corresponding to the geometry of ordinary experience.

Can anyone explain this? I can't find a further explaination anywhere?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation

Comment: @mplungjan is this different from a regular modulo?

Comment: I see floored modulo on the net, but I do not actually know. I just saw the euclid mentioned in the regular modulo in the wiki

Comment: @mplungjan I'll read through the full document, thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a well-documented Javascript modulo bug that shows up when using negative numbers. You can think of `x % 4` as a number wheel:

[image]

- When x goes from 0 into positives, your results are: `0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, ...`.
- When x goes from 0 into negatives, the results are: `0, 3, 2, 1, 0, 3, 2, ...`

But in JavaScript, when you perform `-5 % 4` you get `-1`, which is not the correct answer. It's not even in the list of possible answers. How is it even possible to have a negative remainder?! The answer should be `3`. Here's a list of correct answers, vs incorrect Javascript answers:

```js
1 % 4 = 1   // JS gives you 1
0 % 4 = 0   // JS gives you 0
-1 % 4 = 3  // JS gives you -1
-2 % 4 = 2  // JS gives you -2
-3 % 4 = 1  // JS gives you -3
-4 % 4 = 0  // JS gives you -0
-5 % 4 = 3  // JS gives you -1
```

To make your life easier, Three.js gives you a utility to get the correct answer to circumvent this JavaScript bug. `THREE.MathUtils.euclideanModulo(-5, 4)` gives you the correct answer `3`.

Comment: In my opinion, the JavaScript behavior with `%` is more a peculiarity than a bug, and the result of JavaScript's `%` is not necessarily "incorrect".  (You remain free to disagree with this.)  It is just that `%` behaves differently in different languages.  For example, `-5 % 4` is -1 in JavaScript, Java, and C#, is 3 in Perl, Python, and Ruby, and (I believe) has implementation-defined behavior in C and C++.

Comment: @PeterO. Fair enough. Maybe bug is too strong a word. It's just that I have yet to find the default `%` useful when it comes to negative numbers.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to draw this out. greatly appreciate it